# Can someone explain how this integral of a third derivative works?

Tags: integration, derivatives

I'm reading some notes on the derivation of the Friedmann equation from Newton's formulas  The paper reads:

*The equation of motion for $R_s(t)$ can be obtained from the gravitational acceleration at the outer
edge of the sphere:*
$$\frac{d^2R_s}{dt^2}=-\frac{GM_s}{R_s(t)^2}$$
*Multiplying both sides by $dR_s/dt$ and integrating converts this "acceleration equation" to an "energy equation":*
$$\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{dR}{dt}\right)^2=\frac{GM_s}{R_s(t)}+U$$
I'm afraid I can't follow the r.h.s. of this derivation.  It looks like they took the third integral of the radius and then integrated it over $R_s$, but my intuition tells me that taking the integral of the derivative gets you right back where you started.  Could someone please explain this part of the derivation?

Is $\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{dR}{dt}\right)^2$ just another way of writing $\frac{d^2R_s}{dt^2}$?

Comment: $\left(\frac{dR}{dt}\right)^2$ means that the derivative of $R$ is being squared, not that $R$ is being differentiated twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's work backwards from the end of your question:

> Is $\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{dR}{dt}\right)^2$ just another way of writing $\frac{d^2R_s}{dt^2}$?

No, it's not.  The latter expression is (almost, but not quite) the *derivative* of the former expression.

This might be easier to see if you introduce a change of variable to reduce some of the noise in the formula.  Let's write $u(t) = \frac{dR}{dt}$.  Then the first expression is $\frac12 \left( u(t) \right)^2$.  It's derivative (with respect to $t$) is, by the Chain Rule, $u(t) \cdot u'(t)$.  That is,
$$\frac{d}{dt} \left( \frac12 \left(\frac{dR}{dt}\right)^2 \right) = \frac{dR}{dt}\cdot \frac{d^2R}{dt^2}$$

Now let's try to understand what the text is saying.

> *Multiplying both sides by $dR_s/t$*...

I suspect there is a typo in here, as it should say "Multiplying both sides by $dR_s/dt$".  If we do this, the original equation becomes
$$\frac{d^2R_s}{dt^2} \cdot \frac{dR_s}{dt} =-\frac{GM_s}{R_s(t)^2} \cdot \frac{dR_s}{dt}$$

Now let's integrate both sides with respect to $t$.  We have
$$\int \frac{d^2R_s}{dt^2} \cdot \frac{dR_s}{dt} \, dt =- \int \frac{GM_s}{R_s(t)^2} \cdot \frac{dR_s}{dt} \, dt$$

Let's tackle these two integrals separately.  For the left-hand side, we will use the substitution $u(t) = \frac{dR}{dt}$.  (This is the same substitution I used at the start of this answer!)  Then the left-hand side reads $\int u'(t) \cdot u(t) \, dt$.  This is exactly the same thing as $\int u \, du$, which integrates easily to $\frac12 u^2$.  In other words, the left-hand side is $\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{dR}{dt}\right)^2$.

Now for the right-hand side. This time set $v = R_s(t)$.  Then (setting aside some constants) the integral is $\int v^{-2} dv$, which is easy to integrate, and we get $-\frac1v$.  So the integral on the right is $\frac{GM_s}{R_s(t)}$.

Comment: OK.  This is the part that I think I was missing.  You said $\int u'(t) \cdot u(t) \, dt$ is the same thing as $\int u \, du$.  What rule allows us to do this?  Can you please explain this step further in the answer?

Comment: Are you familiar with substitution as a technique of integration?  Like when you set $u = x^3$ and then write $du = 3x^2 \, dx$?  That's all that's happening here:  $du = u'(t) dt$. It might be confusing because the factors appear out of order:  rewrite the integrand as $u(t) (u'(t)\, dt)$.  Then the part in the parentheses is $du$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{d^2 R}{dt^2} = - \frac{GM}{R^2} \\
\frac{d^2 R}{dt^2} \frac{dR}{dt} = -\frac{GM}{R^2} \frac{dR}{dt} \\
\int_{t_1}^{t_2} \frac{d^2 R}{dt^2} \frac{dR}{dt} dt = \int_{t_1}^{t_2} -\frac{GM}{R^2} \frac{dR}{dt} dt \\
\int_{R'(t_1)}^{R'(t_2)} u du = \int_{R(t_1)}^{R(t_2)} -\frac{GM}{v^2} dv.$$

In the last step, we changed variables on both sides to $u=R'(t)$ and $v=R(t)$ respectively. When doing so, you make the identifications $\frac{d^2R}{dt^2} dt = du$ and $\frac{dR}{dt} dt = dv$, as is normal with integration by substitution.

Now you just do these integrals:

$$\frac{1}{2} R'(t_2)^2 - \frac{1}{2} R'(t_1)^2 = \frac{GM}{R(t_2)}-\frac{GM}{R(t_1)}.$$

If you like, you can instead do an indefinite integral, but the impact of doing different substitutions on different sides of the equation is more confusing in the setting of indefinite integrals IMO.

$\left ( \frac{dR}{dt} \right )^2$ is exactly what it looks like, the square of the rate of change of the radius.

Comment: I don't mean to be dim, but the last step is the one I'm having the most trouble with.  Would you mind completing the derivation?

Comment: @Quarkly Sorry, I actually made a mistake in that step anyway, I'm sorting that out now.